# $M$ is flat $\Leftrightarrow S^{-1}M$ is a flat $S^{-1}R$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra

Hi I have the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a ring and $S\subset R$ multiplicatively closed and $M$ be an $R$-module.
>
> Show: $M$ is flat $\Leftrightarrow S^{-1}M$ is a flat $S^{-1}R$-module.

I think I can show $"\Rightarrow$" but for $"\Leftarrow"$ I don't know how to start. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Don't you need more than this? Should it be $S^{-1}M$ is flat over $S^{-1}R$ *for all* $S$ or something like that?

Comment: I don't think that is a dublicate, since in the other question we look at $M$ as an $R$-modul and then at $M$ as an $S^{-1}R$-modul. But in my question I want to show that $S^{-1}M$ is flat not $M$.

Answer (score 4):

The statement as you wrote it is not correct.
Consider $R=\Bbb Z$ and $S= \Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}$, then $S^{-1}R= \Bbb Q$, and clearly any $S^{-1}R$ module is flat in this case, as $\Bbb Q$ is a field. But not every $\Bbb Z$-module is flat.